# Как сделать так чтобы Youtube Api проигрывал видео в фоновом режиме

Tags: java, android, youtube-api

Я использую Youtube API  ,

```
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
    youTubePlayer.setPlaybackEventListener(this);
    youTubePlayer.setPlaybackEventListener(this);
    if (!b) {
        if (Video_Id.length() > 0)
            youTubePlayer.cueVideo(Video_Id.substring(32));
        else {
            youTubePlayer.cueVideo(Video_Id);
        }
    }
}
```

Получаю ссылку вот отсюда `Video_Id = getIntent().getStringExtra("ytblink");`

Все работает отлично, но теперь надо сделать так чтобы Youtube видео проигрывалась в фоновом режиме?

Answer (score 0):

Раньше можно было так делать и приложения были, сейчас google со своим youtube premium заблокировали данную возможность. Как не пытайтесь на андроиде врятле получится обойти их правила. Если только не скачивать видео полностью и воспроизводить.